# PM2 console.log asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, logging, synchronous, pm2

As per Node.js documentation:

> The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a
>   terminal or a file (to avoid lost messages in case of premature exit)
>   and asynchronous when it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long periods
>   of time).

Now we know that pm2 is listening on `data` event:

```
process.stderr.on('data', function(data){
 var std = file. createWriteStream([LOG_PATH]);
 std.write([LOG]);
});
```

Does this make using `console.log` with pm2 asynchronous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pm2 indeed makes `console.log` become asynchronous.

Though `console.log` and `console.error` are based on:

```
process.stdout.write()
process.stderr.write()
```

Pm2 flushes the logs by using `createWriteStream` from your application and reloads them for display. As your snippet mentioned above, all the logs coming from your application will be written asynchronously into log folder, which is located in `/root/.pm2/logs` by default.

Also, you can notice that there is an issue for discussing Pm2 logging mechanism.

[Is logging asynchronous?](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1087)